# Azure Service Bus Queue - Release locked message back to the queue

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-servicebus-queues, .net-standard

Is there a way to unlock a locked message in the queue before the timeout, so that it is available again to the queue (a way to change the lock timeout to a very small value would be good enough).

A similar functionality is available in AWS SQS, where there is (ChangeMessageVisibility) to change the lock timeout, if the timeout is set to a very small value, the message will be released back to the queue.

The call sequence:

- Send the message from the producer: queueClient.SendAsync
- Receive the message from the consumer: messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync
- The consumer decided that they the message needs to be available again in the queue, this is the step I am asking for.

Comment: You know what, you are silently teaching us AWS.. :)

Comment: And promoting it :) :) I am not explicitly taking any money from Amazon though :) :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to unlock a locked message in the queue before the
>   timeout, so that it is available again to the queue

The method you're looking for is [`Abandon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.abandon?view=azureservicebus-4.1.1). This will release the message lock. From the documentation:

> Abandons the lock on a peek-locked message.

Comment: This option seems like putting it in dead letter queue. I would rather have this in the queue for other consumers to use. Is that possible?

Comment: It shouldn't immediately dead letter the message, that would be the explicit [DeadLetter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.deadletter?view=azure-dotnet) method, **but** it does consume one of the delivery attempts on the message. I haven't been able to locate an API which doesn't consume a delivery attempt while still allowing me to PeekLock yet.